# Pytorch simulation fails to converge on convex loss function when not initialized with 0

Tags: python, pytorch, logistic-regression

My code works when the weights initialized with 0. When I initialize them according to some seed, they fail to converge. This should be a bug since the loss function is convex.

I filtered two labels from MNIST (0 and 1), and then I trained a logistic regression model using pytorch. Since I use only 200 training samples (and 784 parameters), the model should quickly converge to 100% accuracy on the training set. This is not the case when the weights initialize by some seed.

I had some problem to share my code on stackoverflow, so here is a link to the code: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ELe8TIWrXMiXgsB63B0Ss43GPr719rGc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Your data are not rescaled and normalized. If you look at the `images` variable in your training loop it's between 0 and 255 this is in all likelihood hurting your training process.

There are cleaner ways to subsample the dataset as you want, but without modifying too much of your code, using this data loading definition

```
import torchvision.transforms as transforms

#Load Dataset
preprocessing = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToTensor(),
                                    transforms.Normalize((0.1307,), (0.3081,))
                                   ])
train_dataset = dsets.MNIST(root='./data', train=True, transform=preprocessing, download=True)

#Filter samples by label (to get binary classification) and by number of training samples
Binary_filter=torch.add(train_dataset.targets==1, train_dataset.targets==0)
train_dataset.data, train_dataset.targets = train_dataset.data[Binary_filter],train_dataset.targets[Binary_filter]

TrainSet_filter=torch.cat((torch.ones(num_of_training_samples)
                         ,torch.zeros(len(train_dataset.targets)-num_of_training_samples)),0).bool()
train_dataset.data, train_dataset.targets = train_dataset.data[TrainSet_filter], train_dataset.targets[TrainSet_filter]

#Make Dataset Iterable
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset=train_dataset, batch_size=batch_size, shuffle=True)
```

I have ~100% accuracy in about 5-10 epochs.

Comment: Hi,
Sadly it's not the problem. I used your changes.  There is still something very weird in this simulation.

Even if the training set consists of 20 samples, I don't get 100% accuracy on the train (only 90%), while if I initialize the weights at 0, I get 100% accuracy after 7 epochs.
I should get *exacly 100% accuracy on the train*

Comment: Try with `lr=1e-3`. 10^-7 is a really low value that you probably had to use due to not rescaling.

Answer (score 0):

Your loss function (BCE) is convex only with respect to the outputs of the deep network, not with respect to the weights.

You definitely can't assume that any local minimum is also a global minimum.